# Error code 253 running npx react-native init on mac m1

Tags: node.js, react-native, macos, npm

Error appear when running this command: `npx react-native init awesomeproject`

npm version: 6.14.15

node version: v14.17.6

```
npm ERR! code Z_DATA_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -3
npm ERR! zlib: incorrect data check

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/name/.npm/_logs/2022-03-11T17_06_48_110Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'react-native@latest' ] failed with code 253
```

I can't find any solutions for this problem. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Any help is appreciated! thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add some more error log?

Comment: @RohitAggarwal I am not allowed to add the error log, it is too long. The code in code block above is basically the error that appear, when running the command.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And update your npm

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Also, install nvm and use the latest LTS version of node

Comment: Now I got a new error, see below.

Comment: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/name/.npm/_logs/2022-03-11T18_36_36_517Z-debug-0.log